# DVD recording fails with "Power Calibration Error" or "Internal Target Failure"

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, dvd-burning

I'm using a Pioneer DVR-215, firmware version 1.22, on Windows 7 64bit (with various apps, e.g. Nero, DeepBurner) - to try and burn a simple ISO DVD (tried both with and without multisession).

This used to work for me on WinXP (32 bit) up until a few weeks ago when I switched to Windows 7.

Now, I get a "Power Calibration Error" for speeds 8x-20x, and an "Internal Target Failure" when I set the speed at 4x.

I'm using Verbatim media, which have worked for me before with the same burner, manufacturer ID MCC03RG20.

This all seems like a software/driver issue, even though the error messages regard the hardware. Any ideas how I can resolve it? Also, can it have something to do with 32-vs-64 bit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Those do seem to be hardware errors. It could be a coincidence that the drive has stopped working soon after you updated Windows. Do you have another machine running XP that you can move the drive into to confirm it isn't a software thing?

Also, make sure that the version of the tools you are using are compatible with Windows 7 (have you tried the built-in writing facility?) - they may be misreporting errors due to the updated security between XP and 7 not allowing them to take certain actions.